# Sending JSON via PHP sockets

Tags: php, json, sockets

I have this API: http://developers.xstore.pro/documentation/2.2 which says:

### **Communication with the xStation API**

There are two IPs, that can be used interchangeably:

- xapia.x-station.eu
- xapib.x-station.eu

Here are the addresses of DEMO and REAL servers:

- DEMO: main port: 5124, streaming port: 5125
- REAL: main port: 5112, streaming port: 5113.

Both servers use SSL connection.

and I'd like to login to my account. My code looks like this:

```
$data = [
    "command" => "login",
    "arguments" => [
        "userId" => my-id,
        "password" => my-password
        ]   
    ];

$in = json_encode($data);

$service_port = 5124;
$address = gethostbyname('xapia.x-station.eu');

$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
if ($socket === false) {
    echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
}

$result = socket_connect($socket, $address, $service_port);
if ($result === false) {
    echo "socket_connect() failed.\nReason: ($result) " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)) . "\n";
}


socket_write($socket, $in, strlen($in));

while ($out = socket_read($socket, 2048)) {
    echo $out;
}

socket_close($socket);
```

I don't get any errors so connection seems established properly, but at the same time I am not echoing out anything. This is first time I am working with sockets so I am not sure if it's the right approach. Could anyone help me with this or at least point me to right direction? I am using Laravel Homestead.